# What python functions can resolve addresses

Tags: python

I have a system the processes applications that include address on a form.  The database has a address table that has street, city, state, postal code.  For example I have record 100 Main Street Cardiff CA 92007 and second records 100 Main ST Cardiff by the Sea.   How can I resolve these to a master address record with the correct data.

Show me example python code.

I expect the name of any python library and sample code

Comment: Your question reads like a request of solving your task, not a problem that you encountered with solving the task yourself. Did you try anything yourself?